# Why is spacetime pseudo-Riemannian manifold?

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Forgive me for asking, This is a relatively naïve question, though, one i've had for a while now. I know that a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) is a differentiable manifold with a metric tensor that is everywhere non-degenerate, though how does this apply to the curvature of spacetime? Are they perhaps mathematically linked? Is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold still a natural extension of [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry)? Im no mathematician though I enjoy browsing the site to learn more about whatever I can regarding mathematics, physics, and the other branches of the sciences, I hope that one of you lovely people help explain to me the relationship between spacetime curvature and pseudo riemmanian manifolds.

Comment: This isn't really about the curvature, but about the fact that the local symmetry of spacetime is *special* relativity, in which the time dimension is treated differently from the spatial dimensions.  Learning about special relativity is the place to start for understanding this.